# AJAX url request to /home directory with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, absolute-path

My site is split across a public_html directory and a private side /home directory which contains all of my PHP scripts.

I am attempting to utilize jQuery's .ajax request to access a PHP script outside of my public_html directory, but am having trouble doing so. I understand that AJAX requests do not allow for out-of-domain requests, but is there a way to "convince" AJAX of my request's legitimacy since it is in fact within my domain?

My current code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/path/to/script",
    success: function(resp){
        alert(resp);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('%$!@');
    }
});
```

How would I go about being able to access these scripts in directories deeper than my www root directory? I wish to maintain certain privacy and control over my scripts.

Comment: You CAN call scripts outside of your public folder with AJAX. Paths are relative AFAIK, so you use `..` to move up one directory

Comment: I understand that a relative path approach is how AJAX runs, but it doesn't seem to work for my particular needs.

My directory structure is as follows:
public_html/
  css/
  js/
  index.php
resources/
  library/
  scripts/
  config.php

The problem is that I am trying to access the scripts/ directory from the public_html directory. When I attempt a relative path approach, a jQuery url of "../../" simply returns the index.php url, even if I modify the url with more subdirectory requests... How do I access these directories outside of my public_html?

Answer (score 1):

What error message do you get? 
(check the console).  The browser will tell you if the problem is cross origin. 
 You may need to set up alias to that path on your server.  I don't think that Ajax will ever let you go below root without using the "file:///" uri scheme.  I don't know if the file uri scheme can be used in Ajax.  An alias will for sure work.  This is done in your httpd.conf file

Comment: I made the assumption that you were using Apache.  If that is incorrect, you should google for using alias on the server you use.   If you are using Apache, there is some good info here:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html.  Basically all you are doing is taking a path and assigning it a an address in the public_html scope.  If you are not familiar with apache's conf files, it can look daunting, but it's straightforward once you get the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question, so I have three different answers here.  The first
relates to that word "domain" you used.  If you are using http to access the public stuff, and https to access the private stuff, your best option might be to not try.  Browsers are getting very picky about letting AJAX code access stuff outside the method by which the main web page was loaded.  For my own website project, I decided to move everything over to https mode, and left just two files in the directory accessed via http: a copy of "favicon.ico" and a new "index.html", which contains this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="Author" content="Me" />
   <meta name="Copyright" content= "(C) by Me" />
   <title>Switching to https mode ...</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="window.name='Redirect';window.open('https://www.mysite.com/index.html',
 'Redirect');">
 &nbsp;<h1><noscript><span style="color:#ff0000;">
 This site requires JavaScript to work properly.</span></noscript></h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Next answer.  Check your php.ini file for how "open_basedir" is set.  It needs to be a directory that is closer to the trunk of the directory tree than all the directories you expect the Web Server to access for whatever purposes.  Be aware that the way Apache is set up to use PHP, it may sometimes have a copy of the php.ini file in its /bin directory, and you will want the open_basedir setting to be the same in both .ini files.

Last answer: One needs to be very careful using relative paths inside .php files called by AJAX --but first let's review the simple stuff.  Let's suppose your base directory is:

```
 /Base  //(ignoring drive letter and any "baser" directories here)
```

and inside that directory you have some .html files that will call some .php files, also in that directory.  You can access them by using something like this in the JavaScript code for your XMLHttpRequest object, inside one of those .html files:

```
 AJAXobj.open("GET", "./task1.php?URLdata=hi", true);
```

The "./" specifies "same directory as this .html file".  Meanwhile, let us suppose you have a subdirectory:

```
 /Base/SubDir
```

and inside that directory you have some .html files that will call the same .php files in the /Base directory, as before.  You will need this slightly different JavaScript, for the .html files in the subdirectory:

```
 AJAXobj.open("GET", "../task1.php?URLdata=hi", true);
```

The "../" specifies "parent directory of the one containing this .html file".

Now for the tricky stuff.  Suppose, inside that task1.php file, you need to access some data that is in a different subdirectory:

```
 /Base/DataDir
```

It turns out that the location of the .html file MAY determine the path you need to specify inside the .php file!  More specifically:

A) If the task1.php file (in the /Base directory) directly accesses a file in that other (/DataDir) subdirectory, something like this is needed:

```
 file("./DataDir/DatFile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

--and this will be true regardless of where the .html file is located, that calls task1.php

B) If the .php file creates a string to the file, and returns that string for AJAX processing (because more JavaScript code in the .html file is going to access the data file), then the string that PHP creates WILL depend on the location of the .html file, either:

```
 "./DataDir/DatFile.txt"
```

for any .html file in the /Base directory, or

```
 "../DataDir/DatFile.txt"
```

for any .html file in /Base/SubDir

A simple solution here might be to have two very similar .php files, say task1a.php and task1b.php  Another possibility, though, involves specifying an absolute path instead of a relative path:

```
 "https://www.mysite.com/DataDir/DatFile.txt"
```